# App from USB always shows verifying app dialog

Tags: mac, applications, catalina, usb, verify

I have a USB drive, and I decided to transfer a few apps from my Mac to the USB that took up a lot of space. Now every time I launch an app from the USB, it always shows the verifying dialog.

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: After verification is done, does it ask whether it needs to warn you or not ? It happens with dmgs downloaded from the internet.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it does.

Comment: then while opening the app, check not warn about this dmg from now on & it'll be fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the box

> Don't warn me when opening applications on this disk image

and then hit open. Note that I don't know how to revert this change.

[image]